# Front end for system ordering

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I am developing a microservice that enables business partners to order systems for common customers:

```
/*
  ordering.js - Terminal ordering JavaScript library.

  (C) 2017 HOMEINFO - Digitale Informationssysteme GmbH

  This library is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this library.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

  Maintainer: Richard Neumann <r dot neumann at homeinfo period de>

  Requires:
    * jquery.js
    * sweetalert.js
    * homeinfo.js
    * his.js
*/
'use strict';

var ordering = ordering || {};


/*
    Static globals.
*/
ordering._BASE_URL = 'https://top.secret.com/endpoint';
ordering._ORDERS_ENDPOINT = ordering._BASE_URL + '/order';
ordering._CUSTOMERS_ENDPOINT = ordering._BASE_URL + '/customers';
ordering._CLASSES_ENDPOINT = ordering._BASE_URL + '/classes';
ordering._OSS_ENDPOINT = ordering._BASE_URL + '/oss';


/*
    Runtime globals.
*/
ordering.orders = ordering.orders || [];
ordering.customers = ordering.customers || [];
ordering.classes = ordering.classes || [];
ordering.oss = ordering.oss || [];


/*
    Displays an error using sweetalert.
*/
ordering.error = function (title, text, type) {
    return function () {
        swal({
            title: title,
            text: text,
            type: type || 'error'
        });
    };
};


/*
    Queries orders from the API.
*/
ordering._getOrders = function () {
    return his.auth.get(ordering._ORDERS_ENDPOINT).then(
        function (orders) {
            ordering.orders = orders;
        },
        ordering.error('Fehler.', 'Konnte verfügbare Bestellungen nicht abfragen.')
    );
};


/*
    Queries customers from the API.
*/
ordering._getCustomers = function () {
    return his.auth.get(ordering._CUSTOMERS_ENDPOINT).then(
        function (customers) {
            ordering.customers = customers;
        },
        ordering.error('Fehler.', 'Konnte verfügbare Kunden nicht abfragen.')
    );
};


/*
    Queries classes from the API.
*/
ordering._getClasses = function () {
    return his.auth.get(ordering._CLASSES_ENDPOINT).then(
        function (classes) {
            ordering.classes = classes;
        },
        ordering.error('Fehler.', 'Konnte verfügbare Terminal-Klassen nicht abfragen.')
    );
};


/*
    Queries classes from the API.
*/
ordering._getOSs = function () {
    return his.auth.get(ordering._OSS_ENDPOINT).then(
        function (oss) {
            ordering.oss = oss;
        },
        ordering.error('Fehler.', 'Konnte verfügbare Betriebssysteme nicht abfragen.')
    );
};


/*
    Performs a HIS login.
*/
ordering._login = function () {
    var queryString = new homeinfo.QueryString();
    return his.session.login(queryString.userName, queryString.passwd);
};


/*
    Initializes the page.
*/
ordering.init = function () {
    ordering._login().then(
        ordering._getData().then(
            ordering._initPage
        )
    );
};


/*
    Submit form.
*/
ordering._submitForm = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();     // Avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    his.auth.post(ordering._ORDERS_ENDPOINT, jQuery('#orders').serialize()).then(ordering._resetForm);
};


/*
    Resets the form.
*/
ordering._resetForm = function () {
    document.getElementById('orders').reset();
    ordering.init();
};


/*
    Initialization function.
*/
ordering._getData = function () {
    var getOrders = ordering._getOrders();
    var getCustomers = ordering._getCustomers();
    var getClasses = ordering._getClasses();
    var getOSs = ordering._getOSs();

    return Promise.all([getOrders, getCustomers, getClasses, getOSs]);
};


/*
    Refreshes the orders list.
*/
ordering._renderList = function () {
    var tableContainer = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
    tableContainer.innerHTML = '';
    tableContainer.appendChild(ordering._dom.list());
};


/*
    Renders the orders input.
*/
ordering._renderOrders = function () {
    var formContainer = document.getElementById('formContainer');
    formContainer.innerHTML = '';
    formContainer.appendChild(ordering._dom.orders());
};


/*
    Initializes the page.
*/
ordering._initPage = function () {
    ordering._renderList();
    ordering._renderOrders();
    jQuery('#orders').submit(ordering._submitForm);
};


/*
    Deletes the respective order.
*/
ordering._deleteOrder = function (id) {
    return his.auth.delete(ordering._ORDERS_ENDPOINT + '/' + id).then(ordering._getData).then(ordering._renderList);
};


/*
    Adds an order.
*/
ordering._addOrderForm = function () {
    var orderForms = document.getElementById('orderForms');
    var order = ordering._dom.order(true);
    orderForms.appendChild(order);
};


/*
    Deletes the respective order form.
*/
ordering._deleteOrderForm = function (index) {
    var orderForms = document.getElementById('orderForms');
    var order = document.getElementById('order_' + index);
    orderForms.removeChild(order);
};


/*
    DOM model.
*/
ordering._dom = ordering._dom || {};
ordering._dom.COLUMNS = [
    'Konto', 'Bestelldatum', 'Bearbeitungsstatus', 'Kunde', 'Klasse', 'Betriebssystem', 'Adresse', 'Anmerkung',
    'Stornieren'];


/*
    ID of orders form.
*/
ordering._dom.ORDERS = 0;


/*
    Builds an order set.
*/
ordering._dom.orders = function () {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('id', 'orders');

    var orderForms = document.createElement('div');
    orderForms.setAttribute('id', 'orderForms');
    orderForms.setAttribute('class', 'row row-center');

    var firstOrder = ordering._dom.order();
    orderForms.appendChild(firstOrder);

    form.appendChild(orderForms);
    form.appendChild(ordering._dom.buttonAddOrderForm());
    form.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
    form.appendChild(ordering._dom.submit());
    return form;
};


/*
    Creates a button to add an order form input for a further terminal.
*/
ordering._dom.buttonAddOrderForm = function () {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success');
    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'ordering._addOrderForm();');
    button.textContent = 'Weiteres Terminal hinzufügen.';
    return button;
};


/*
    Creates a button to delete the respective oder inputs.
*/
ordering._dom.buttonDeleteOrderForm = function (index) {
    var buttonDeleteOrderForm = document.createElement('button');
    buttonDeleteOrderForm.setAttribute('onclick', 'ordering._deleteOrderForm(' + index + ');');
    buttonDeleteOrderForm.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
    buttonDeleteOrderForm.textContent = 'X';
    return buttonDeleteOrderForm;
};


/*
    Creates a button to delete the respective order.
*/
ordering._dom.buttonDeleteOrder = function (id) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');
    button.setAttribute('onclick', 'ordering._deleteOrder(' + id + ');');
    button.textContent = 'X';
    return button;
};


/*
    Creates the title for the terminal order.
*/
ordering._dom.caption = function (index, additional) {
    var caption = document.createElement('legend');

    var textNode = document.createTextNode('Terminal ');
    caption.appendChild(textNode);

    if (additional) {
        caption.appendChild(ordering._dom.buttonDeleteOrderForm(index));
    }

    return caption;
};


/*
    Builds a single order.
*/
ordering._dom.order = function (additional) {
    if (additional == null) {
        additional = false;
    }

    var index = ordering._dom.ORDERS;
    ordering._dom.ORDERS += 1;

    var order = document.createElement('fieldset');
    order.setAttribute('id', 'order_' + index);
    order.setAttribute('class', 'row');

    var caption = ordering._dom.caption(index, additional);
    order.appendChild(caption);

    var columnSelects = document.createElement('div');
    columnSelects.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-6');

    var customerSelect = ordering._dom.customerSelect(index);
    columnSelects.appendChild(customerSelect);

    var classSelect = ordering._dom.classSelect(index);
    columnSelects.appendChild(classSelect);

    var osSelect = ordering._dom.osSelect(index);
    columnSelects.appendChild(osSelect);

    var columnAddress = document.createElement('div');
    columnAddress.setAttribute('class', 'col-md-6');

    var address = ordering._dom.address(index);
    columnAddress.appendChild(address);

    order.append(columnSelects);
    order.append(columnAddress);
    return order;
};


/*
    Builds a default option for a dropdown list.
*/
ordering._dom.defaultOption = function (text) {
    var defaultOption = document.createElement('option');

    var attributeSelected = document.createAttribute('selected');
    defaultOption.setAttributeNode(attributeSelected);

    var attributeDisabled = document.createAttribute('disabled');
    defaultOption.setAttributeNode(attributeDisabled);

    defaultOption.textContent = text;
    return defaultOption;
};


/*
    Builds the customer selection dropdown menu.
*/
ordering._dom.customerSelect = function (index) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.setAttribute('required', true);
    select.setAttribute('name', 'customer_' + index);
    select.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

    var defaultOption = ordering._dom.defaultOption('Kunde*');
    select.appendChild(defaultOption);

    for (var i = 0; i < ordering.customers.length; i++) {
        var customer = ordering.customers[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', customer.id);
        option.textContent = customer.company.name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }

    return select;
};


/*
    Builds the class selection dropdown menu.
*/
ordering._dom.classSelect = function (index) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.setAttribute('required', true);
    select.setAttribute('name', 'class_' + index);
    select.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

    var defaultOption = ordering._dom.defaultOption('Klasse*');
    select.appendChild(defaultOption);

    for (var i = 0; i < ordering.classes.length; i++) {
        var class_ = ordering.classes[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', class_.id);
        option.textContent = class_.full_name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }

    return select;
};


/*
    Builds the operating system selection dropdown menu.
*/
ordering._dom.osSelect = function (index) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.setAttribute('required', true);
    select.setAttribute('name', 'os_' + index);
    select.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

    var defaultOption = ordering._dom.defaultOption('Betriebssystem*');
    select.appendChild(defaultOption);

    for (var i = 0; i < ordering.oss.length; i++) {
        var os = ordering.oss[i];
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', os.id);
        option.textContent = os.name + ' ' + os.version;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }

    return select;
};


/*
    Builds the address input fields.
*/
ordering._dom.address = function (index) {
    var address = document.createElement('fieldset');
    address.setAttribute('class', 'form-group');

    var street = document.createElement('input');
    street.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    street.setAttribute('required', true);
    street.setAttribute('name', 'street_' + index);
    street.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Straße*');
    address.appendChild(street);

    var houseNumber = document.createElement('input');
    houseNumber.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    houseNumber.setAttribute('required', true);
    houseNumber.setAttribute('name', 'houseNumber_' + index);
    houseNumber.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Hausnummer*');
    address.appendChild(houseNumber);

    var zipCode = document.createElement('input');
    zipCode.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    zipCode.setAttribute('required', true);
    zipCode.setAttribute('name', 'zipCode_' + index);
    zipCode.setAttribute('placeholder', 'PLZ*');
    address.appendChild(zipCode);

    var city = document.createElement('input');
    city.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    city.setAttribute('required', true);
    city.setAttribute('name', 'city_' + index);
    city.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Ort*');
    address.appendChild(city);

    var annotation = document.createElement('input');
    annotation.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    annotation.setAttribute('name', 'annotation_' + index);
    annotation.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Anmerkung');
    address.appendChild(annotation);

    return address;
};


/*
    Builds a submit button.
*/
ordering._dom.submit = function () {
    var submit = document.createElement('input');
    submit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    submit.setAttribute('value', 'Kostenpflichtig bestellen.');
    submit.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
    return submit;
};


/*
    Builds the list of existing orders.
*/
ordering._dom.list = function () {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.setAttribute('id', 'list');
    table.setAttribute('class', 'table  table-hover');

    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var th;

    for (var i = 0; i < ordering._dom.COLUMNS.length; i++) {
        th = document.createElement('th');
        th.setAttribute('scope', 'col');
        th.textContent = ordering._dom.COLUMNS[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    thead.appendChild(tr);

    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    var empty = true;

    for (var attr in ordering.orders) {
        if (ordering.orders.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
            empty = false;
            tbody.appendChild(ordering._dom.listItem(ordering.orders[attr]));
        }
    }

    if (empty) {
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.setAttribute('align', 'center');
        h2.textContent = 'Keine Bestellungen vorhanden.';
        return h2;
    }

    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    return table;
};


/*
    Builds the list items for each existing order.
*/
ordering._dom.listItem = function (order) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    var columnAccount = document.createElement('td');
    columnAccount.textContent = order.account.name;
    row.appendChild(columnAccount);

    var columnIssued = document.createElement('td');
    columnIssued.textContent = order.issued;
    row.appendChild(columnIssued);

    var columnAccepted = document.createElement('td');
    var notProcessedYet = 'Noch nicht bearbeitet.';

    switch (order.accepted) {
    case null:
        columnAccepted.textContent = notProcessedYet;
        break;
    case undefined:
        columnAccepted.textContent = notProcessedYet;
        break;
    case true:
        columnAccepted.textContent = 'Angelegt.';
        break;
    case false:
        columnAccepted.textContent = 'Auftrag abgewiesen.';
        break;
    }

    row.appendChild(columnAccepted);

    var columnCustomer = document.createElement('td');
    columnCustomer.textContent = order.customer.company.name + ' (' + order.customer.id + ')';
    row.appendChild(columnCustomer);

    var columnClass = document.createElement('td');
    columnClass.textContent = order.class_.name;
    row.appendChild(columnClass);

    var columnOs = document.createElement('td');
    columnOs.textContent = order.os.name + ' ' + order.os.version;
    row.appendChild(columnOs);

    var columnAddress = document.createElement('td');
    var address = order.address;
    columnAddress.textContent = address.street + ' ' + address.house_number + ', ' + address.zip_code + ' ' + address.city;
    row.appendChild(columnAddress);

    var columnAnnotation = document.createElement('td');
    columnAnnotation.textContent = order.annotation || '-';
    row.appendChild(columnAnnotation);

    var columnDelete = document.createElement('td');
    columnDelete.appendChild(ordering._dom.buttonDeleteOrder(order.id));
    row.appendChild(columnDelete);

    return row;
};


jQuery(document).ready(ordering.init);
```

The corresponsing HTML document is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Terminal Bestellung</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://libraries.homeinfo.de/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://libraries.homeinfo.de/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css">
    <script src="https://libraries.homeinfo.de/jquery/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://libraries.homeinfo.de/bootstrap/latest/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://libraries.homeinfo.de/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://javascript.homeinfo.de/homeinfo.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://javascript.homeinfo.de/his/his.js"></script>
    <script src="https://javascript.homeinfo.de/his/session.js"></script>
    <script src="ordering.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 align="center">Ihre Bestellungen bei HOMEINFO</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="tableContainer" class="row"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="formContainer" class="row"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'd like to have general feedback especially on the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for specific questions, we can provide better feedback.

A few thoughts:

- if you're including jQuery, go ahead and use it for DOM generation, as it will be much more concise and readable, instead of all the bulky `createElement`, `setAttribute` code. And the event handlers can be done through jQuery a little nicer.
- if you're allowed, you have good names for the functions in the comments, and I'd use them. For example, `listItem` would be more clearly `buildListItem`; `ordering._dom.list` would probably be better `buildExistingOrdersTable` (it's not a list!). I would find `buildSubmitButton` clearer than `ordering._dom.submit`.